# Useful extensions for MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Can anyone suggest some useful MediaWiki extensions? I've installed PDF export, syntax highlight, file link protocol, submit in toolbar and enforce strong password. But I'm still eager to know any good/handy extensions.

Comment: Keep in mind that additional extensions potentially increase your work maintaining the install, and may add a range of new and exciting security vulnerabilities in future. This is just a small suggestion to apply some balance to your enthusiasm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the extensions [BreadCrumbs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs), [FCKeditor](http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net/) and [InputBox](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Inputbox) quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Like pQd wrote, it depends on the wiki's purpose. However, you can take a look at the extensions being used on Wikipedia and Wikia by going to these pages. Click on a few of them that you think might be useful on your site to check them out. And since Wikipedia is using them, you can be sure the extensions are stable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Version
http://vgsales.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Version

Answer (score 2):

"Simple security", if you need to control user permissions per page.

Answer (score 0):

it all depends what you use the wiki for. i'm quie happy user of [semantic medawiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) extension. it gives me idea to organize and query information stored in the wiki.